# ES6 generator: why the argument passed to the first next() function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

Here is my sample code:

```
function *g() {
  while (true) {
    console.log(yield)
  }
}

var gen = g();
gen.next(3); // {value: undefined, done:false}
gen.next(3); // 3 {value: undefined, done:false}
gen.next(3); // 3 {value: undefined, done:false}
```

Why the first argument passed to the first `next()` function doesn't work ? And why the value property's value is `undefined`, shouldn't it be the argument value passed in ?

Comment: You're yielding nothing, so why do you expect to get the argument back?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what happens in a generator.

The first call initializes the generator (and returns an iterator), doesn't run any internal code.

From then on, every call to `.next(value)` on the iterator passes the `value` to be returned from the currently paused `yield` and continues execution to the next `yield` (or end of the function), returning the `yield`-ed (or returned) value.

Now, what is the currently paused `yield` on the first `.next` call? There isn't one, we started execution from the top of the function instead.

Hence the first value is `undefined` no matter what you pass into the first `next` call (it's just ignored).

As far as the `yield`-ed value being `undefined`, you get what you `yield`.

```js
function *g() {
  yield;     // yields undefined
  yield 3;
  yield 'a';
}

for (const v of g()) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

Comment: TIL `for (const v of g())`, I didn't realize you could do that! In hindsight, it's rather the point.